# Cant find "Texture Coordination" on Blender 2.79

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor

[image: screenshot of issue]

I searched here previously and one of the answers were saying that you should be on Cycles Render to appear. But even on cycles render it doesn't show.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a thing in Blender as “Texture Coordination”.

If you are talking about Texture Coordinate node, you can find it under Input category in the Add menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>) or in the <kbd>t</kbd> panel in the Node Editor:

[image]

Terminology is important. It is better to be as exact as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have the search field at the top of shift A menu, don't use the spacebar